# how to detect and open link in new tab/window/winform in DotNetBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetbrowser

I using [DotNetBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) and want to open link in **new window/winform/tab** when click on link however when we click on any link **DotNetBrowser** open them in current window
I know i should override **DotNetBrowser** events however i don't know which event, Also i try with `CreatePopupHandler` and not work, also i can't find any sample **DotNetBrowser** anywhere hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreatePopupHandler` handler [is invoked](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/gs/popups.html) when the engine wants to know whether pop-up can be created or not. Basically, you can use it either to allow or suppress pop-ups creation in general.

If the `CreatePopupHandler` handler allows creating a pop-up, the `OpenPopupHandler` handler is invoked. In this handler, you can access the created pop-up and display it if necessary.

When you initialize a WinForms `BrowserView`, it automatically configures the given `IBrowser` instance with the default implementation of the `CreatePopupHandler` and `OpenPopupHandler` handlers.

In this case, there are two scenarios when links are opened in a new window (pop-up):

1. The `window.open()` JavaScript function:

```js
window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", 
    "resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
```

2. A link with `target` attribute:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open Google</a>
```

To load any URL in a separate window or tab on a navigation attempt (e.g. clicking a link), you will need to intercept all or required navigation requests using [StartNavigationHandler](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/gs/navigation.html#filtering-urls). In the handler implementation, you need to create a new window or tab with browser, load this URL into it, and cancel its loading in the original browser. For example:

```cs
browser.Navigation.StartNavigationHandler =
    new Handler<StartNavigationParameters, StartNavigationResponse>((p) =>
    {
        // Intercept all navigation requests to the URLs that start 
        // with "https://dotnetbrowser" and load them into a new form
        if (p.Url.StartsWith("https://dotnetbrowser"))
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
            {
                LoadNewWindow(p.Url);
            }));
            return StartNavigationResponse.Ignore();
        }
        return StartNavigationResponse.Start();
    });
browser?.Navigation.LoadUrl("https://teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser");
```

The `LoadNewWindow` implementation:

```cs
private void LoadNewWindow(string url)
{
    var browser1 = engine.CreateBrowser();

    BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };

    browserView.InitializeFrom(browser1);

    Form form = new Form();

    form.Width = 800;
    form.Height = 600;

    form.Closed += delegate
    {
        form.Controls.Clear();

        if (!browser1.IsDisposed)
        {
            browser1.Dispose();
        }
    };

    form.Controls.Add(browserView);
    form.Show();

    browser1.Navigation.LoadUrl(url);
}
```